# HTML Selection box JQuery issue regarding showing/hiding a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a website which involves the client needing to choose a device type from a list, before being submit to a database.

I need the functionality so that when the user selects the option "Chromebook" on my HTML select drop down menu, a message is displayed below.

I've achieved this but with varying success.

When the page first loads, the div with my message is already visible, despite the selection box showing its default option. Only when an option is selected (Other than Chromebook) does the div disappear).

I've mocked up the bit that matters in a JSFiddle as well as posting my code below.

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jackanyon/fbv7178w/4/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="media">
 <select>
   <option selected hidden disabled value="">Select One...</option>
   <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
   <option value="chromebook">Chromebook</option>
   <option value="desktop">Desktop</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div class='notice'>
    Some text...
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready( function() { 
if($('#media select').val() == 'chromebook'){ //'.val()'
       $('.notice').show();
   }


$('#media select').change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'chromebook'){ //'.val()'
       $('.notice').show();
       return true;
   }
   $('.notice').hide();
});
});
</script>
```

How could I fix my code? Or is there a better method of achieving the correct outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

- [.toggle( display )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display): display : Use true to show the element or false to hide it.
- [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to fire the change event immediately after its creation:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#media select').change(function(){
    $('.notice').toggle($(this).val() == 'chromebook');
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="media">
    <select>
        <option selected hidden disabled value="">Select One...</option>
        <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
        <option value="chromebook">Chromebook</option>
        <option value="desktop">Desktop</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class='notice'>
    Some text...
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is best so far I see. Don't know who is down voting all of these answers without giving reason.

Comment: Thanks for this, love the small amount of code you used. Thanks for the explanation as well. Not sure on the downvotes, it seems someone has downvoted each answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to display your text to `none` on page load

```js
$(document).ready( function() { 
if($('#media select').val() == 'chromebook'){ //'.val()'
       $('.notice').show();
}


$('#media select').change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'chromebook'){ //'.val()'
       $('.notice').show();
       return true;
   }
   $('.notice').hide();
});
});
```

```css
.notice{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="media">
 <select>
   <option selected hidden disabled value="">Select One...</option>
   <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
   <option value="chromebook">Chromebook</option>
   <option value="desktop">Desktop</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div class='notice'>
    Some text...
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies, didn't realise it needed to be added to my CSS. Unsure on the downvotes though, all the answers have been downvoted?

Comment: @JackAnyon some people are lame :) but anyway, learn from your mistakes. goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `$('.notice').hide();` at the beginning of your .ready function. Nothing is hiding the notice initially

Answer (score 0):

Just a small update in your code will work. Add `$('.notice').hide();` after your document ready line as below.

```js
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('.notice').hide();
    
    if($('#media select').val() == 'chromebook'){ //'.val()'
           $('.notice').show();
       }


    $('#media select').change(function(){
       if($(this).val() == 'chromebook'){ //'.val()'
           $('.notice').show();
           return true;
       }
       $('.notice').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="media">
 <select>
   <option selected hidden disabled value="">Select One...</option>
   <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
   <option value="chromebook">Chromebook</option>
   <option value="desktop">Desktop</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div class='notice'>
Some text...
</div>
```